# How to search a value of column of one dataframe into other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have 2 dataframes DF1['mobile','pwd'] ,DF2['mobile','pwd']

DF1 :
[image]

DF2 :
[image]

I want to check whether the value of df2['mobile'] is present in df1['mobile'] or vice a versa.
the possible solutions i have tried isin() and merge(). But i  think this won't work due to unequeal length.

The ouptput that i want is

df1 : [image]

Comment: Unequal length shouldn't be an issue with `isin` or `merge`. What code are you trying and what errors are you getting?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: Its returning false even if value matches ...using isin()

Comment: Please create a [reprex] so one doesn't have to guess what code you're actually using.

Comment: And please, please post data as **copyable text** and not as images. We expect to be able to reproduce the problem on your data...

Answer (score 0):

i found out the solution for this .

`df1.assign(Indf2=df1.mobile.isin(df2.mobile).astype(bool))`